# Is it possible to deploy a Ubuntu Cloud in an ESX-server

Tags: cloud

I wondered whether it is possible to set up a Ubuntu Enterprise cloud for testing purposes inside a VM-Ware infrastructure.

I know that the cloud controller is able to run inside a VMWare, but I didn't find information regarding the node controller.

Answer (score 2):

Found out the answer on - openstack based environments can be installed inside a VM but they are only running in an emulation mode with very low performance.

Comment: Yeah, I don't use Vmware, but with Virtualbox we need use QEMU or LXC. Virtualbox or ESX don't support Xen or Kvm as good and directly.